# Copy pictures to Windows with some files broken/corrupt

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I want to backup my pictures from my Android 4.4 phone to my Windows PC but I'm struggling to copy them the normal windows copy way. It seems that at some point many of the images have somehow corrupted and since I have hundreds of pictures on my phone, finding the images one by one in File Manager (CyanogenMod) is a real hassle.

The normal windows copy mode fails when I try to copy the files off the device through USB which actually crashes the entire Windows Explorer process and I have to restart it from task manager.

Then I thought trying to copy in segments by going in to the Camera folder and copying piece by piece. But windows fails to fully read the directory (probably due to corrupt files) and again crashes Windows Explorer.

I also tried creating a zip file from the folder on the device but it seems to also fail making it.

How could I copy the folder to my windows pc even if it has some files corrupt/broken?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on Android 9. Some of the JPG images that were about 3 MB on the file are "corrupt" according to the picture viewer, and are 20 MB to 50 MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the `Media Transfer Protocol` (MTP) isn't working right on your phone. In that case, you have two options:

- transfer wirelessly using an app
- transfer manually with debugging enabled

## Wirelessly

This is the more straightforward method. Using an app like [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/), you get a GUI for transferring files from your phone to your computer wirelessly.

## ADB

This is significantly more involved. You've got to [install Android Debugging Tools](http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378) on your computer, enable USB debugging on your phone (after activating developer mode), then install the relevant drivers (google!). Following that, you do something like:

```
adb pull /storage/sdcard0/DCIM
```

to transfer all the contents of `DCIM` to your computer.

Comment: AirDroid didn't work as well. it failed to open the Camera directory and also when I tried downloading the folder, it at some point failed. But with ADB (I already had it configured on my device) I managed to download all of my images. I had to download two broken images on the way but I finally managed to get them on my PC. Many thanks :)